# Can not install nokogiri gem on dockerfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, nokogiri

I try to setup run rails project with docker, so I build a dockerfile as below

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential

# for mysql
RUN apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev

RUN apt-get install -y git-core zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev software-properties-common libffi-dev nodejs yarn

RUN gem install bundler

ENV APP_HOME /myapp
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ADD Gemfile* $APP_HOME/
RUN bundle install

ADD . $APP_HOME
```

When I run `docker build .`, it always through errors like below:

```
 => ERROR [10/11] RUN bundle install                                                                                                                                                                                  1.0s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 > [10/11] RUN bundle install:                                                                                                                                                                                             
#14 0.850 Resolving dependencies...                                                                                                                                                                                        
#14 0.909 Unable to find a spec satisfying nokogiri (~> 1.8) in the set. Perhaps the                                                                                                                                       
#14 0.909 lockfile is corrupted? Found nokogiri (1.11.2-x86_64-darwin) that did not match
#14 0.909 the current platform.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c bundle install]: exit code: 7
```

So please help me.

Comment: Your host is not `x86` and this is not matching the architecture of your CPU. I assume you are building it on `Apple M1`

Comment: No I dont use Apple M1, the problem I see I install `libxslt-dev liblzma-dev patch` for nokogiri gem

Answer (score 0):

I've just change my Dockerfile, and it works for me

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
# for mysql
RUN apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev

RUN apt-get install -y libxslt-dev liblzma-dev patch git-core zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev software-properties-common libffi-dev nodejs yarn

RUN gem install bundler
RUN gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby

ENV APP_HOME /myapp
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ADD docker_app/Gemfile* $APP_HOME/
# RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
RUN bundle install

ADD docker_app/. $APP_HOME
```